# Is there an efficient way to use regular expressions to extract data from an HTML string?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, regex, parsing

I'll be doing all this is node.js
In my scenario I have an html string and it contains this string:

```
// there is html code above ^^^
<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="MTYwNjU1NzAwOHRor9RCGkXDyFBLI7HUPCwb-v46P012KayHiFSHTKDdW7CUBvjiKTHoC3lVtRBOBIGwSRA4_ojvfiG3Khnsd54." />
//and html code below vvv
```

is there a regular expression that could extract only the value of the token? e.g.:

```
MTYwNjU1NzAwOHRor9RCGkXDyFBLI7HUPCwb-v46P012KayHiFSHTKDdW7CUBvjiKTHoC3lVtRBOBIGwSRA4_ojvfiG3Khnsd54.
```

I've also looked into html parsing npm modules, no such luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've also looked into html parsing npm modules, no such luck.

You can use for example [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom):

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(`<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="MTYwNjU1NzAwOHRor9RCGkXDyFBLI7HUPCwb-v46P012KayHiFSHTKDdW7CUBvjiKTHoC3lVtRBOBIGwSRA4_ojvfiG3Khnsd54." />`);
let elm = dom.window.document.getElementById("token");
if (elm) console.log(elm.value);
```

Output

```
MTYwNjU1NzAwOHRor9RCGkXDyFBLI7HUPCwb-v46P012KayHiFSHTKDdW7CUBvjiKTHoC3lVtRBOBIGwSRA4_ojvfiG3Khnsd54.
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, the regex is reasonably straight forward.

```
const htmlString = '<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="MTYwNjU1NzAwOHRor9RCGkXDyFBLI7HUPCwb-v46P012KayHiFSHTKDdW7CUBvjiKTHoC3lVtRBOBIGwSRA4_ojvfiG3Khnsd54." />';
const regex = new RegExp("value=\"(.*?)\"");
result = regex.exec(token)[1];
```

In plain English, how the regex works is it searches the html string until it finds the characters `value="`, then it picks up all the next characters until the next `"`. Looking at the regex itself to explain more clearly:

```
regex = "value=\"(.*?)\""
```

The `\"` searches for the double quotes character. The slash escapes the double quote, so javascript doesn't mistakenly think you're ending the string.

The parentheses around `.*?` are a matching group. The reason we call the 1st element of result, i.e `result = regex.exec(token)[1]`, is to pull out the match group

The `.` matches all characters, the `*` matches any number of them, and the `?` makes it non-greedy, so it stops at the next quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

You can put that value by this method:

```
let inputValue = getElementById(token).value;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for this comment, but ive made a mistake, im not reading a local html file, im reading response.body from a get request to a website

Comment: @djsnoob if I understood you, you are doint get requst to the server and get that html tag with token in value attribute? But why don`t you get just object with this token inside? Or I am not right?

Comment: because im pretty sure the get request returns a string, hence why I asked for regex @Danil Sadonov

Comment: @djsnoob but if you get that by response from server you will get it in string by the way, you just get or "<input value"token" ..." or "token", what the main idea, do you need this token in other type, not string?